# How to preserve searched data on coming back from another fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have two fragments(A & B). In fragment A, I have two edit boxes and a search button.

Upon click of search button, I am populating a list view with searched results below the button. On list item click, I am passing values using bundle to  fragment B using below code:

```
FragmentB details = new FragmentB();

Bundle detailsBundle = new Bundle();

detailsBundle.putString("ProdCode", _prodCode);
detailsBundle.putString("ProdName", _prodName);
detailsBundle.putString("UnitPrice", _unitPrice);
detailsBundle.putString("StockValue", _stockValue);
detailsBundle.putString("Indicator", _indicator);
detailsBundle.putString("OpenOrderValue", _openOrderValue);
detailsBundle.putString("OpenInvoiceValue", _openInvoiceValue);

details.setArguments(detailsBundle);


FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.container, details, "Details");
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

But when I click back button on Fragment B, populated list in fragment A getting disappeared. How can I preserve the searched results in listview and also how can I clear the text from the edit boxes on coming back from fragment B to fragment A.

[Edit]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

private Button button1, button2, button3, button4;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFrgament1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFrgament2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFrgament3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFrgament4);


        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        FirstFragment initialFragment = new FirstFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.containerLinearLayout, initialFragment);
        ft.commit();


        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        button4.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Fragment newFragment;

        int id = v.getId();

        switch(id)
        {
        case R.id.btnFragment1:

        newFragment = new FirstFragment();

        break;

        case R.id.btnFragment2:

        newFragment = new SecondFragment();

        break;

        case R.id.btnFragment3:

        newFragment = new ThirdFragment();

        break;

        case R.id.btnFragment4:

        newFragment = new FourthFragment();

        break;

        default:            
            newFragment = new FirstFragment();          
            break;

        }

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.containerLinearLayout, newFragment);
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.commit();


        }
```

SecondFragment has two edit boxes and a button(Search). I am displaying searched results in listview below button. When I click on list item, I am passing details to next fragment using the bundle as shown above. When I come back by hitting back button from details fragment to previous fragment, list getting disappeared.

Comment: Not sure so leaving it as a comment. 1) In A have the EditText's as field variables and do setRatainInstance(true) in onCreate. This should (I think) keep whatever values you store (unless ofcourse you instansiate an entirely new fragment when adding A). 2) you could just use setText("") on the EditTexts in B whenever you move back, or alternatively in onCreateViews

Comment: How is your Fragment A implementation? I will answer you because I think I know what's wrong, but to be sure I need the implementation.

Comment: @RenanBandeira I have divided my activity into two fragments. On left side I have 4 buttons. Upon click on button, I am opening respective fragment on right side. I have posted my code. Please check.

Now in right side, I have two edit boxes and a button(Search). I am  displaying searched results in a listview below the button. On list item click I am passing details to next fragment using bundle as shown in my query. When I come back from details fragment to previous fragment, list is getting disappeared.

Comment: To be honest, I would like to see the fragment code, not the activity one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
editTextName.setText("");
```

in onResume() method in Fragment A

Also in onResume() populate data & call listAdapter like this

```
adapter = new ExampleListAdapter(getActivity());
Listv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your `ListView` with the id: `android.R.id.list` (`android:id="@android:id/list"`) and make your `Fragment` be a `ListFragment` (`class FragmentA extends ListFragment`). Then, you can have your listview calling the method `getListView()` and populate it. You can define your adapter as well, calling `setListAdapter()`.

I have had these kind of problems, but since I've made this, I've never had problems about lists.

Comment: Renan, I am using custom Array adapter.

Comment: it doesn't matter the type of the adapter.
`ArrayAdapter adapter ...` and then, `setListAdapter(adapter)` This is the good way to do it, because the listfragment knows that you are dealing with a list.